# Google Mock: How to copy memory from a pointer in a mock argument?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have following function mocked with signature:

```
uint32 Icc_u_SendMessage(te_IccTransferType e_DataTxType, SW_e_IccMsgType e_MsgType, uint8 *const pui8_DataRef, const uint32 ui32_DataSize, const SW_e_CoreIdent e_MsgDestination)
```

The interesting argument for me is the Arg2 (`pui8_DataRef`).

Call in the function under test:

```
MessageBuffer<ET_t_SignalToGs> s_locPayloadToGs; (Local)
iccReturnValue = c_ICC_Messages::ICC_ui32_SendMessage(c_ICC_Messages::e_TxSendRefCopyData, e_msg, (uint8*)&locPayloadToGs, u_size, e_dst);
```

I'd like to copy the whole contain of `s_locPayloadToGs` for checks.
The Problem with `SaveArgPointee()` is that the third argument is (`uint8 *`) and I get only the first Byte.

How could I do a kind of `memcpy` from a mock argument in the `EXPECT_CALL()` ? like following:

```
c_event_transceiver::MessageBuffer<c_event_transceiver::ET_t_SignalToGs> expectedPayload;
EXPECT_CALL(obj_MockIccMessages, ICC_ui32_SendMessage(c_ICC_Messages::e_TxSendRefCopyData,
                                                            e_MsgToGs,
                                                            _,
                                                            sizeof(expectedLocPayload),
                                                            c_event_transceiver::a_ConfigMapGsToCore[0].e_core)).WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArgPointee<2>(&expectedPayload), Return(retSendMessage)));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define your [own action](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#defining-actions):

```
ACTION_P(SavePayload, expectedPayload)
{
    auto beginOfArray = arg2;
    auto sizeOfArray = arg3;
    auto endOfArray = beginOfArray  + sizeOfArray ;

    expectedPayload->assign(beginOfArray , endOfArray);
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    //  that only my guess how it is possible to store payload
}
```

And just replace `SaveArgPointee<2>(&expectedPayload)` with `SavePayload(&expectedPayload)` in your tests.

But, what you really needs is a [multi argument matcher](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#matching-multiple-arguments-as-a-whole) - that will match that payload is as it is, something like that:

```
MATCHER_P(matchPayload, expectedPayload)
{
    auto beginOfArray = get<2>(arg);
    auto sizeOfArray = get<3>(arg);
    auto endOfArray = beginOfArray  + sizeOfArray ;

    return expectedPayload->equalTo(beginOfArray , endOfArray);
           //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
           //  that only my guess how it is possible to compare payloads   
}
```

And use it with `With(matchPayload())` clausure:

```
c_event_transceiver::MessageBuffer<c_event_transceiver::ET_t_SignalToGs> expectedPayload;
// expectedPayload - build it to be as this you expect
...

EXPECT_CALL(obj_MockIccMessages, ICC_ui32_SendMessage(c_ICC_Messages::e_TxSendRefCopyData,
                     e_MsgToGs,
                     _,
                     sizeof(expectedLocPayload),
                     c_event_transceiver::a_ConfigMapGsToCore[0].e_core))
.With(matchPayload(&expectedPayload)).WillOnce(Return(retSendMessage));
```